# JavaFX SDK 19 contain no .dll Files to create JAR with external libraries

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, dll, jar

in previous versions of JavaFX, you could build jar files from project by building artifacts using .dll files within the bin folder of JavaFX. However, in later versions of JavaFX, there are absolutely no bin files or .dll files. Does anyone know a work around this?

Comment: Read the info at openjfx.io on [runtime images](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. If you, e.g., download JavaFX from Gluon and unpack the distribution file all the .dylibs, .dlls, etc. are contained in the lib/ folder. (Just verified with openjfx-20-ea+11_osx-x64_bin-sdk.zip)

The jars in the maven repository are structured a little bit differently. The have platform specific variant, e.g., javafx-graphics-20-ea+11-mac.jar which contain the binary libs at the top-level folder.

Going modular, as @jewelsea suggested above, is yet another option, depending on what you want to achieve.